# Show variable from different model as a field in Profile in DJANGO Admin

Tags: python, django

In my Django application I have `Profile` and `Report` models.
https://ibb.co/b9YwsH

In Django admin I am able to view both report and Profile.
Reports has variables `Toxicity` and `Sportsmanship`.

I am trying to get the variables `TOXICITY` and `SPORTSMANSHIP` and display the total of them both as a field in my `PROFILE` view for admin(eg. total:25)
https://ibb.co/bVBrsH

ERRORS:

```
<class 'apps.api.admin.ProfileAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 
'list_display[2]' refers to 'user_report', which is not a callable, an 
attribute of 'ProfileAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'api.Profile'.
```

Code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from ..api.models import Profile,Report, 
Game_Api_Connection, Feedback


class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def user_report(self):
        total = TOXICITY + SPORTSMANSHIP
        return self.user.total

admin.site.register(Report,ReportAdmin)


class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('birth_date', 'sessions_played', 'user_report')

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: Can you post your models too ? I want to see the relation.

Comment: intendation the function `user_report` does nothing, I also would register a Model manager on your model which takes care of that sum, because it is a data transformation which shouldn't belong in the admin.

Comment: Models are linked in the the IBB URL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .api.models import Profile,Report, Game_Api_Connection, Feedback


class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(Report,ReportAdmin)


class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('birth_date', 'sessions_played', 'user_report')

    def user_report(self):
        total = self.report.TOXICITY + self.report.SPORTSMANSHIP
        return total

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: This works,but in my admin view,instead of the actual variable,under the user_report field I get:  <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor object at 0x7fe7610b5978>

Answer (score 0):

If you want `user report` in `Profile` admin, you should implement your method in `Profile` admin.

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('birth_date', 'sessions_played', 'user_report')
    def user_report(self, obj):
        # your logic should be here
        # You should get all `obj`(current profile) reports here 
        return total
```

This why the admin list display looks for a attribute or a callable in the same class and model.